# Diffeomorphism and allowable surface patch

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

[image]
This is from Pressley’s book. How does f being a diffeomorphism imply the existence of F which is smooth and bijective?

Comment: This is just the definition of what it means for $f$ to be a diffeomorphism. See page 83 of your text.

Comment: I get that f has a inverse since it is a diffeomorphism but why f composition with sigma 1 is written in terms of sigma 2 and another F? I guess I’m unable to see a connection. Or getting confused with the notation.

Comment: It's explained right before the proposition. Note that $F=\sigma_2^{-1}\circ f\circ \sigma_1$.

Comment: Yes but does this make use of the fact that f is a diffeomorphism? In the place where you mention it is just said that f is any map and not necessarily a diffeomorphism. Here the inverse is used for sigma 2 but Pressley begins ‘since f is a diffeomorphism’. Just wondering does that make any difference in the proof? EDIT : Got it! He uses that fact to establish the inverse of F. Am I correct?

Comment: Basically, but there are steps in showing this. Do you understand the definition of smoothness of a map $f$?

Comment: When the components of that map has partial derivatives of all orders?

Comment: Nope. $f$ is smooth if the map $\sigma_2^{-1}\circ f \circ \sigma_1$ is smooth. See the top of page 83.

Comment: Yes it is given so.

Comment: Well, the properties of $F$ follow from the definition.